# Value Error: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, svm

While practicing Support Vector Regression Model I got this error

Here is my data set:

Here is independent variable X:

Here is dependent variable Y:

Here is X_train

Here Is Y_train

Error body:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2de23298b092> in <module>()
----> 1 sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in inverse_transform(self, X, copy)
   1020             estimator=self,
   1021             dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
-> 1022             force_all_finite="allow-nan",
   1023         )
   1024 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    763                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    764                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 765                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array)
    766                 )
    767 

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.01150915].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
y = y.reshape(len(y), 1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the test input `[[6.5]]` which you are providing to `sc_X.transform())` in the last line of your code.

Try to find the shape of X and test input using `numpy.shape` and make sure that number of dimensions should be 2 in both cases. So you will get something like `(Xi, Xj)`, `(Ti, Tj)`. Also, *Xj* must be same as *Tj* (basically number of features must match for the train and test data)

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset has 8 columns, here is how you pick X and y

```
values = dataset.values
X = values[:,0:8]
y = values[:,8]
```

take it from there, note too that values is deprecated, instead it is to_numpy()